# Assign variable value in asp.net textbox in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding a textbox like this dynamically in my aspx file:

Here is my code:

```
foreach (DataRow info in myDataTable.Rows)
{
    //draw html table and add controls
    <input type="text" name="myTxt" id="myTxt" runat="server" />
    <tr><td><%=Convert.ToString(info[0][1]) %></td></tr>
    //more code here
}
```

How can I assign particular cell value to textbox?

I tried using <%=Eval(info[0][1])%> but it is not working as expected

Some guidance with this would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**Updated Q:**

```
 <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Col1</th>
                    <th>Col2</th>
                    <th>Col3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%
                    var rowId = 0;
                    foreach (System.Data.DataRow info in MyTable.Rows)
                    {
                %>      <tr>
                            <td> //want to draw a textbox which show value of column
                            <td><%=Convert.ToString(info[0]) %></td>
                            <td><%=Convert.ToString(info[3]) %></td>
                    }
                 %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: my code is in aspx; not in .cs due to requirement

Comment: How is there a `foreach` in there? Is this razor? There seems to be a mix of server-side code and mark-up.

Comment: No, it is not MVC. You can use foreach in asp.net as well

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I don't see the syntax in place here that would allow you to. You've followed neither convention from the two available examples on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178135(v=vs.100).aspx I may quite well be wrong, I just don't see how you'd mix the two up like this so fluidly without razor.

Comment: did you try like this ? Text='<%#Bind("ID")%>' or Value='<%#Bind("ID")%>'

Comment: I did try Bind..it doesn't work either. I guess, it works with different context..

Comment: Try adding .net Textbox control instead of HTML and then bind it with value. or you already tried it and it didn't work

Comment: @user1480864 - you can't just keep trying different suggestions and saying "doesn't work", your code MUST be fundamentally wrong, you can't mix server-side code and mark-up like that. Address that issue first, then you'll be closer to solving it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the rows value and assign it:

```
myTxt.Value = info["column"].ToString();
```

or by column index:

```
myTxt.Value = info[index].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, that there is some constraint and you have to do this in `aspx` only. Keeping that in  mind, you can use following code. And make a note here multiple inputs will have id = `myTxt` , you need to handle this. Else good approach is to follow `Repeater` and use databinding.

```
<table>
    <%
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow info in myDataTable.Rows)
        {
            string txtid = "myTxt" + counter.ToString();
            %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name='myTxt<%=txtid %>' id='myTxt<%=txtid %>' value="<%=Convert.ToString(info[0]) %>" /></td>
        <td><%=Convert.ToString(info[0]) %></td>
    </tr>

    <% 
            counter = counter + 1;
    }%>
</table>
```

To retrieve changed textbox value on `PostBack`, use this `Request.Form["myTxtmyTxt0"]`, `Request.Form["myTxtmyTxt1"]` etc..

Comment: how do I assign value to textbox?

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it in wrong way. You need to instantiate `TextBox` control class and then attach it's properties and values. Finally add the newly created control to your webform's control collection like below. This may not guarantee any particular position where the control will be added. To guarantee the specific position you need to use a [`place holder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control and then add your textbox control to that `place holder`.

```
foreach (DataRow info in myDataTable.Rows)
{
    TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
    tbx.Name = "some_name";
    tbx.Text = info[idx].Tostring(); 
    this.webform1.Controls.Add(tbx);
}
```

Example of using `Place Holder` Control

Add a place holder control to your ASPX design

```
  <asp:PlaceHolder id="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"/>
```

Then in your code behind `.cs` file add the newly created TextBox control to place holder control collection

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tbx);
```

(OR)

If you already have declared a textbox named `myTxt` in your design then you can just attached the value saying

```
foreach (DataRow info in myDataTable.Rows)
{
  this.myTxt.Text = info[0] as string;
}
```

Comment: how i will render this textbox through aspx not with .cs

Comment: updated initial Q again. I tried this solution but didn't work. I will end-up seeing textbox with same value when I have multiple rows as panel will also duplicate as it is specific in design time